# Unable to get logged in username in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-users

I am trying to get User as foreignkey in a model but getting error.

1. When I try:

```
qr.claimed = True
user = get_object_or_404(User,id=request.user.id)
qr.branch = user
qr.save();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'
```

2. When I try to POST:

```
qr.claimed = True
get_user = request.POST.get('branch')
user = User.objects.get(id=get_user)
qr.branch = user
qr.save();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'POST'
```

3. When I define user in another python file and try to fetch from there:

```
qr.claimed = True
get_user = pythonfile.user
user = User.objects.get(id=get_user)
qr.branch = user
qr.save();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <function user at 0x0E777E38>.
```

- **request**.user -> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'
- **request**.POST -> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'POST'
- **Any error with request or missing any package to install/import?**

**UPDATE:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def decodeAjax(request):

    if request.POST:
        decodedData = barCode.decode(request.POST['imgBase64'])
        if decodedData:

            json_data = json.dumps(decodedData)
            print(json_data)
            
            return JsonResponse(json_data,safe=False)

        return JsonResponse({"code" : 'NO BarCode Found'})
```

```
def decode(request):
    # Find barcodes and QR codes

    imgstr = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', request).group(1) #url
    image_bytes = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imgstr))
    im = Image.open(image_bytes)

    arr = np.array(im)[:, :, 0]
    decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(arr)
    #print(decodedObjects)


    # return decodedObjects.Decoded
    # Print results
    data = []

    for obj in decodedObjects:
        qrs = Scanner.objects.all()
        for qr in qrs:
            if obj.data.decode('utf-8') in qr.ID:
                dt = 'Successfully Claimed!'
                btn = 'Claim Another'
                img = 'tick.gif'

                if qr.claimed == True:
                    dt = 'Already Claimed at %s'%(localtime(qr.scanned_at))
                    img = 'cross.png'
                else:
                    qr.claimed = True
                    qr.save();
                break
            else:
                dt = 'Invalid QR Code'
                btn = 'Try Another'
                img = 'cross.png'

        data.append({
            "code":obj.data.decode('utf-8') ,
            #"type": obj.type,
            "dt": dt,
            "btn":btn,
            "img":img
        })
    return data
```

Comment: It means your `request` is not a `HttpRequest`. Please show the *full* view. Likely you assign something to the `request`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added the function. Please check

Comment: But is `decode` a view, it does not return a HTTP response, so it looks like this is not a view, but some "helper function".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, decode is helper function of decodeAjax. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

You check the method with:

```
@csrf_exempt
def decodeAjax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        decodedData = barCode.decode(request.POST['imgBase64'])
        # …
```

The item you pass to `decode` is *not* a `HttpRequest` object, but the image in base64 encoding. You thus might want to rename this to:

```
def decode(base64img):
    imgstr = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', base64img).group(1)
    # …
```

If you need the request somewhere, you will need to pass `request`, not <s>`request.POST['imgBase64']`</s>.

furthermore I would really advise *not* to make methods with a CSRF exeption. You can send the CSRF token as specified in the [*AJAX* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: Actually, the code I updated works perfectly. But, I want to add user as foreignkey:

user = get_object_or_404(User,id=request.user.id)

qr.branch = user

as mentioned earlier

Comment: @PanchamJain: you can do that by passing the `request` to the function, not `request.POST['imgBase64']`.